# Borrar el texto de un input en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Usé React para crear una lista de tareas, esta funciona pero quiero implementar que una vez que le de al botón de añadir tarea, el texto que aparece en el input se elimine para que el usuario no tenga la necesidad de hacerlo, uso `preventDefault` en el formulario para evitar que se actualice la página y poder pasar la información para el componente padre donde todo se procesa.

Intenté al hacer un `reload()` (este es el mismo caso que no use `preventDefault` y se actualizaría la página) o un `reset()` al llamar a la función del evento `submit` y  no me sirve y no me funcionó respectivamente. Ahí les dejo el componente donde implemento el formulario.
Confío en que me puedan ayudar.

```
import '../stylesheet/TaskForm.css'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function TaskForm( {onSubmitTask} ) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const takeChangeInput = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    } 
    

    const takeSendForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newTask = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            text: input,
            compled: false
        }
        {onSubmitTask(newTask)};
    }
    
    return (
        <form action=""  onSubmit={takeSendForm} className="task-form">
            <button className="task-button">
                Add Task
            </button>
            <input type="text" className="task-input" 
            placeholder="Write a new task" name="text"
            onChange={takeChangeInput} />

        </form>
    );
}

export default TaskForm;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al usar `setInput('')` se actualiza el valor de la variable `input` pero el valor que aparece en el DOM sigue ahí, por lo que se debe borrar manualmente, debido a que se está usando el evento `onChange` y este vuelve a actualizar el valor del `input` al enviar (pulsar el botón o dar enter). Esto indica que se debe actualizar directamente el valor del DOM (en este caso lo hice por `id`) y además actualizar el valor del `input` para que no se dé el caso que: estando vacío el `input` del DOM, se almacene la tarea anterior y al enviar aparezca nuevamente tarea anterior (misma tarea).
(Gracias al amigo TD Perez por dar una pista importante)
Así quedó implementado:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import '../stylesheet/TaskForm.css'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function TaskForm( {onSubmitTask} ) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const takeChangeInput = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    } 
    

    const takeSendForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newTask = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            text: input,
            compled: false
        }
        const inputDOM =document.getElementById('task-input');
        inputDOM.value='';
        setInput('');
        {onSubmitTask(newTask)};
    }
    
    return (
        <form action=""  onSubmit={takeSendForm} className="task-form">
            <button className="task-button">
                Add Task
            </button>
            <input id='task-input' type="text" className="task-input" 
            placeholder="Write a new task" name="text"
            onChange={takeChangeInput} />

        </form>
    );
}

export default TaskForm;
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero en este caso seria mejor que no se modifique directamente el doom sino hacerlo por estados, asi como yo lo coloque en el ejemplo de mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para esto tienes que asignar a tu input el valor de tu variable input y una vez ya mandaste la informacion o ya obtuviste los datos necesarios solo mandas al setInput y le vandas '' de la siguiente forma

```
import '../stylesheet/TaskForm.css'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function TaskForm( {onSubmitTask} ) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const takeChangeInput = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    } 
    

    const takeSendForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newTask = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            text: input,
            compled: false
        }
        setInput('')
        onSubmitTask(newTask);
    }
    
    return (
        <form action=""  onSubmit={takeSendForm} className="task-form">
            <button className="task-button">
                Add Task
            </button>
            <input type="text" className="task-input" value={input}
            placeholder="Write a new task" name="text"
            onChange={takeChangeInput} />

        </form>
    );
}

export default TaskForm;
```

Edit:

Para que se borre se tinene que hacer

```
setInput('')
```

Con esto ya se cambio el valor del input y para que se refleje en html en el tag input tiene que llevar la propiedad value

<input value={value} .../>

Te dejo un ejemplo aqui para que entiendas mejor

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
function Hello() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')
  const [task, setTask] = React.useState([])
  const submit = () =>{
    setTask([...task, input])
    setInput('')
  }
  const takeChangeInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  return (
  <>
  <button onClick={submit}>
                Add Task
  </button>
  <input value={input} type="text" className="task-input" placeholder="Write a new task" name="text" onChange={takeChangeInput} />
  <ul>
  {task.map( (element, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{element}</li>
  ))}
  </ul>
  </>
  )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Con esto puedo asignar el valor '' (vacío) al input pero la parte visual sique ahi debido a que no puedo actualizar la página

Comment: Recorda que al input tenes que mandarle el valor input como propiedad, mo lo puse en la respuesta

Comment: No logré entender esto último, podrías escribirlo en el código?